# Python 3 - send2trash module install error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-module

I am trying to install the 3rd party Python module send2trash using pip - I am attempting this from the command line.

Originally I encountered an Import Error as there was "no module named _wingreg". To resolve this, I used the 2to3 tool to update the python script ("Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\appdirs.py") that was attempting to import the _winreg module and convert it to winreg.

I then attempted to install send2trash, again using pip from the command line and encountered a FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]. The offending line is in the appdirs.py script - line 224: directory, _type = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, shell_folder_name)

Has anyone else encountered this problem or one similar?

For context:

I am on Windows 10
I am using Python 3.5.1
I am trying to install a 3rd party module from the command line using pip

I am relatively new to Python and programming so apologies if my terminology is not exactly on point. Any help would be greatly received!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first:
Try to install pywin32 from here :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

depends on you operation system and the python version that you are using. Normally 32bit version should works on both 32 and 64 bit OS.

after that:
go to the scripts path on python and run the prompt like administrator.

execute: python pywin32_postinstall.py -install